Access PowerBI Report - When User having multiple Microsoft Account from different Org
We have published several PowerBI reports accessible to all authenticated users within our web application via an iframe, with a total user base of over 60,000. Everything works well because we have SSO configured with the same Identity Provider (IDP).
However, we encounter issues when users are already logged in with a different Microsoft account, leading to an error message stating "report not found." While this is technically expected, it is not ideal from a user perspective. We want to understand if we can embed the client or tenant ID in the report URL to ensure it always checks for the session of a specific tenant or Microsoft account, avoiding these issues for users.
We have a couple of options but bot feasible at this point of time for us so looking for alternatives.

Training the user base, which is challenging given the current
circumstances.

Embedding the report using Javascript

Register the application in Azure AD.
Configure API permissions.
Create a client secret.
Implement server-side authentication and token generation.
Embed the report client-side.



The problem with this approach is that the access token would be accessible at the UI layer, which we are not comfortable sharing.
Please suggest if there is a way to enforce the PowerBI report URL to use a specific tenant or account.
